# Room Database Error when espresso test "Cannot access database on the main thread"

Tags: android, android-room, android-espresso, android-livedata

I am using espresso for testing and I am getting an error while executing below method.

```
viewModel.getData().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { options ->
            Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated: $options")
            val data = options.filter { option -> option.type!! == OptionType.DATA}

            updateData.updateUIComponent(data)
        })
```

get data method return a LiveData object. and this is working fine in the Fragments but not workng in the espresso test class

```
Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
```

This is my test class

```
@LargeTest
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
open class BaseIntegrationTest {

    @get:Rule
    val instantTestExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    lateinit var navController: TestNavHostController

    lateinit var fragmentScenario: FragmentScenario<DetailsFragment>


    @Before
    fun initTest() {

        navController = TestNavHostController(
            ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext()
        )

    }

    @Test
    fun launchFragment() {

        val bundle = Bundle()

        fragmentScenario =
            launchFragmentInContainer(bundle, themeResId = R.style.Theme_mainTheme)

        fragmentScenario.moveToState(Lifecycle.State.STARTED)

        UiThreadStatement.runOnUiThread {
            navController.setGraph(R.navigation.app_navigation_graph)
        }
        fragmentScenario.onFragment { fragment ->

            //CollectFeedbackFragment()
            Navigation.setViewNavController(fragment.requireView(), navController)
        }

        onView(withId(R.id.progressBar)).isVisible()
    }

}
```

Comment: The callback from liveData is not running on the main thread in prod, but tests (which you haven't shown) normally use a `InstantTaskExecutorRule` or similar that swaps the background executors for a synchronous one (show your test?). Either you need to modify your db (in your test) to allow queries on the main thread, or use `runBlocking` variants to await.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini I already used InstantTaskExecutorRule but it didn't work for me. I am wondering that normal Fragments and unit test classes both a running in the UI thread but in the fragments, that is working fine but in the test class its behave different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue By using Dispatchers.IO and Dispatchers.Main

```
class SampleViewModel : ViewModel() {

    fun getData():DataLiveData {
        viewModelScope.launch {

            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {

                 // here I am seding the Room db call
                
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
               // I am updating the MutableLiveData object here
                }
            }
        }
        return mutableLiveData
    }
}
```

And don't forget to inject dispatchers instead of hardcoding.
Click [here](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/coroutines-best-practices)!